# title of the post always fixed when scrolling page

Tags: wordpress, scroll

I use wordpress.

user: user

pass: 123abc

I wish the title of the post always fixed when scrolling page.
http://www.correnteparaobem.com.br/onde-se-encontra-a-casa-de-deus

For example:

We opened an article, the title we have in place standard.
Once down the page, it keeps it on top of the site.
When climbing the screen, he returns to the place of origin.

I tried to guide me through this tutorial: http://pt.w3support.net/index.php?db=so&id=1216114

I changed the title to a div:

```
< div class="postheader"> < ? php the_title ();> < / div>
```

I tried the css:

```
. postheader {

margin: 0.2em 0;

padding: 0;

font-size: 18px;

color: # 3f5e73;

background-color: # ffffff;

     color: # 3f5e73;
     height: 30px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     width: 400px;
     z-index: 100;
}
```

And in the body, this script:

```
$ (window). scroll (function (e) {

   $ el = $ ('. postheader');

   if ($ (this). scrollTop ()> 0 & & $ el.css ('position')! = 'fixed') {

     $ ('. postheader'). css ({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0 px '});

   }

});
```

Not getting results

Comment: let me guess. Did you put everything including code to google translate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS, use `position: fixed;`. Also, check for extra spaces in your code...